# calculating and storing mean of values from table column

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, backend, knex.js

I have a trucks table and a (food) trucks table and truck_ratings. The truck_reviews table stores reviews that customers can leave for food trucks:

[image]

[image]

As shown above, the `truck_reviews` table includes a column for a `star_rating`. I want to take all the star ratings for a particular truck and calculate the mean value of them and then store that mean value in an `avg_rating` column in the trucks table. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. Help?

In case it helps put things into context, a friend sent me this advice on how to proceed:

> you could create a weighted average based on the number of reviews. So
>   you'll also need to create a column that keeps track of the total
>   number of reviews. Every time a new rating comes in, you can do:
>
> ```
> (current_avg * current_total_no_of_ratings) + new_rating / current_total_no_of_ratings + 1
> ```
>
> That will give you the new avg. Whenever you do this make sure you
>   always increment the total number of ratings in the table by 1

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend updating the trucks table every time the new truck review comes (e.g. avg_rating column). It creates complexity and additional operations on the database, which can be avoided.

First of all please re-think if you need to keep this value in the database. You can always extract it with a simple query like:

```
SELECT AVG(star_rating) FROM truck_reviews WHERE truck_id = x
```

But if you really need to see it together in the database with all remaining trucks data, I recommend you to create a [View](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-views.htm). You can query it just like you query the table. To create it you need something like:

```
CREATE VIEW trucks_view AS
SELECT *, 
(select AVG(star_rating) from trucks_reviews where truck_id = trucks.id) as 'avg_rating'
FROM trucks
```

And then you can ask the view about truck details

```
SELECT * FROM trucks_view
```

It will return exactly what you need

Comment: I actually don't need it in the database. That wasn't my first thought at all. That was just what a friend suggested. I had the same concerns as you, actually. Let me try the first way you suggested.

Comment: How can I update this method to get all trucks and return the avg_rating for each truck. I see that you've suggested how to do so in mySql when I am retrieving a specific truck by id. But my issue is a little different. 1) I need to be able to do this in node.js 2) I already have a method that accomplishes this when I get individual trucks. I need the avg_rating when I get all trucks. Here is the method to get all trucks as is: ```function getAllTrucks() {
    return db('trucks as t')
        .select('*')
}```

Comment: Can you please provide the information, which library (in node.js) do you use to query the database? Then I can hep with creating a proper query. Any way - if you create a view in a way I showed you - then you can query it like 
`function getAllTrucks() { return db('trucks_view  as t') .select('*') }`

Comment: I'm using knex.js for my queries

Comment: I'm not really familiar with knex, but I suppose you should use `knex.raw` (http://knexjs.org/#Raw). So it wil be sth like: `knex.raw('SELECT *, (select AVG(star_rating) from trucks_reviews where truck_id = trucks.id) as avg_rating FROM trucks')`. But still - it's nothing bad with using database views, so you can try both approaches.